# PulseAudio cannot open PCM device

Tags: alsa, embedded, pulse-audio

I have an IMX6Q based board and want to game with PulseAudio.
My board has three sound devices:

```
# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: tlv320aic3xaudi [tlv320aic3x-audio], device 0: HiFi tlv320aic3x-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: tlv320aic32x4au [tlv320aic32x4-audio], device 0: HiFi tlv320aic32x4-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: imxhdmisoc [imx-hdmi-soc], device 0: i.MX HDMI Audio Tx hdmi-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The device I would like to use is `hw:1,0`:

```
aplay -D plughw:1,0 /usr/share/sounds/2.wav
```

This worked fine.

But at start the PulseAudio does not detect PCM devices. 
When I try to manually configure PulseAudio via

```
# pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device="hw:1,0"
```

I get the response:

```
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

and manually starting with

```
# pulseaudio --system -vvvv --log-meta
```

returns:

```
I: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/client.c:80 pa_client_new()] Created 1 "Native client (UNIX socket client)"
I: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/protocol-native.c:5012 pa_native_protocol_connect()] Client authenticated anonymously.
D: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/protocol-dbus.c:799 pa_dbus_protocol_add_interface()] Interface org.PulseAudio.Core1.Client added for object /org/pulseaudio/core1/client1
D: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/protocol-native.c:2601 command_auth()] Protocol version: remote 29, local 29
D: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/protocol-native.c:2664 command_auth()] SHM possible: no
D: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/protocol-native.c:2682 command_auth()] Negotiated SHM: no
D: [pulseaudio][modules/alsa/alsa-util.c:673 pa_alsa_open_by_device_string()] Trying hw:1,0 with SND_PCM_NO_AUTO_FORMAT ...
I: [pulseaudio][(alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c:1667 _snd_pcm_hw_open()] Invalid value for card
I: [pulseaudio][modules/alsa/alsa-util.c:680 pa_alsa_open_by_device_string()] Error opening PCM device hw:1,0: No such file or directory
E: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/module.c:175 pa_module_load()] Failed to load module "module-alsa-sink" (argument: "device=hw:1,0"): initialization failed.
I: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/client.c:102 pa_client_free()] Freed 1 "pactl"
I: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/protocol-native.c:4903 pstream_die_callback()] Connection died.
D: [pulseaudio][pulsecore/protocol-dbus.c:835 pa_dbus_protocol_remove_interface()] Interface org.PulseAudio.Core1.Client removed from object /org/pulseaudio/core1/client1
```

How can I get PulseAudio to load the device?

Comment: Was `pulseaudio --system -vvvv --log-meta` the full command run to obtain the last output?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?